# When did "fair" start to be used in German?

Tags: anglicism

One of the characters in the book I'm reading says the following :

- »Aber Herrmann ist älter und viel größer als ich.  Außerdem bin ich erst acht.  Das ist nicht fair.«

The book is *Magus, die Bruderschaft* by Arno Strobel. (I'll get to the *Zauberberg* when my German's improved a bit more.)  It was originally published in 2007. That particular bit of dialogue is set in 1970.  Is *fair* an adjective that could have been used as early as that year?  My feeling is no, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DWDS says](https://www.dwds.de/wb/fair)

> fair Adj. ‘anständig, ehrlich’, im 19. Jh. aus dem Engl. ins Dt. übernommen. Zuerst auch als Qualitätsbezeichnung ‘ausgezeichnet, vorzüglich’ bei Warenangeboten üblich, dann vornehmlich ein Ausdruck der Sportsprache im Sinne von ‘anständig, den Bestimmungen gemäß’.

Or take a look at the [DWDS-Korpus](https://www.dwds.de/r?q=fair&corpus=kern&date-start=1900&date-end=1999&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_asc&limit=50), which gives examples from newspapers, books etc. for this word starting in 1900. You will find examples from as early as 1910. Therefore one can say there is no paradox using this word in 1970.

Comment: I think *anachronism* would be a better word than *paradox*.

Answer (score 3):

Hier noch ein Zitat aus Heinrich Heine, Reisebilder, vierter Teil (1831):

> […] beide Richtungen mit gleicher Liebe umfassen und zugleich durch deren Gegensatz neutralisiert werden, so erklärt sich sehr leicht seine Unparteilichkeit bei der Schilderung der Aristokraten und Demokraten aus Cromwells Zeit, eine Unparteilichkeit, die uns zu dem Irrtume verleitete, als dürften wir in seiner Geschichte Napoleons eine ebenso treue **fair-play-Schilderung** der französischen Revolutionshelden von ihm erwarten.
>   [Heine: Reisebilder. Vierter Teil. Deutsche Literatur von Lessing bis Kafka, S. 77144 (vgl. Heine-WuB Bd. 3, S. 430)]

Die älteste lexikalische Quelle, die ich gefunden habe, ist Daniel Sanders, Fremdwörterbuch (1871), [GoogleBooks](https://books.google.de/books?id=BGkVAAAAYAAJ&hl=de&pg=PA371#v=onepage&q=fair&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

Mit [google-NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fair&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfair%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfair%3B%2Cc1) kann man die Verbreitung von Wörtern in Druckwerken verfolgen, muss die Funde allerdings meist stichprobenartig kontrollieren, um beispielsweise nicht Wörterbüchern, Zitaten aus dem Englischen u.a. Fehlinterpretationen zu unterliegen. Hier ein Beispiel:

[Forum: österreichische Monatsblätter für kulturelle Freiheit](https://books.google.de/books?id=VsOfqp9D1igC)

> 1960 - ‎Snippet-Ansicht - ‎Mehr Ausgaben Fair play, Herr Kommandant.“
>   Kraft sah ihm sekundenlang ins Gesicht. „Fair play“, murmelte er.
>   „Sport.“ Dann sagte er: „Niemand wird in den Ofen gehen. Aber dieser
>   Schlag von dir war kein fair play. Es war ein Tiefschlag.“

Als Zeitzeuge kann ich zwar nicht für 1970, aber für Mitte der 70er bestätigen, dass "das ist fair/unfair" schon üblich war.

Comment: *Als Zeitzeuge kann ich zwar nicht für 1970, aber für Mitte der 70er bestätigen, dass "das ist fair/unfair" schon üblich war.* Dem stimme ich zu (wobei wir - wenn ich mich nicht gerade sehr irre - auch noch aus derselben Gegend stammen)

Comment: Danke für die Antwort!  Mein Gefühl ist anscheinend einfach falsch.  Ich wusste nicht, dass man Recherchen mit Ngram auf spezifische Bücher oder Quellen beschränken konnte.